# Twitter friends' timeline as a feed?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to get my twitter timeline (i.e. the tweets posted by my friends) as an RSS or atom feed? I've heard that you could've used https://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.rss in the past, but it's not working anymore.

My main concern is to extract this timeline to Yahoo Pipes, so any other method that will do this may also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is no longer possible now that Twitter requires OAuth and won't accept basic authentication: Twitter doesn't support Basic Authentication anymore and instead requests which require authentication need to be signed with OAuth.

Further reading: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/moving-from-basic-auth-to-oauth

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect, but if you can find your user id, this will show the most recent statuses for all the twitter users you follow, so it is similar:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.rss?user_id=[your id]

For example:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.rss?user_id=179698068

Or the user name version

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.rss?user=[username]

For example:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.rss?user=stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

You can access any individual public users timeline in RSS, ATOM, XML and JSON formats:

https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/***username***.rss

Just replace the extension .rss with either .rss, .atom, .xml or .json if you'd like to use a different format.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a combined feed of everyone they follow, not just a specific user.  Nice tip with the extensions though.

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to do OAuth authentication for private feeds.

Comment: I was asking about my combined friends' timeline.

Comment: I get an error if I try that link with my username: `<error code="34">Sorry, that page does not exist</error>`

Comment: Sorry for the downvote... but I feel like this gives readers false hope whenn they are tryingn to solve another problem.